# Keep only sentences in corpus that contain specific key words (in R)

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, corpus, quanteda

I have a corpus with `.txt` documents. From these `.txt` documents, I do not need all sentences, but I only want to keep certain sentences that contain specific key words. From there on, I will perform similarity measures etc.

So, here is an example.
From the data_corpus_inaugural data set of the quanteda package, I only want to keep the sentences in my corpus that contain the words "future" and/or "children".

I load my packages and create the corpus:

```
library(quanteda)
library(stringr)


## corpus with data_corpus_inaugural of the quanteda package
corpus <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural)
summary(corpus)
```

Then I want to keep only those sentences that contain my key words

```
## keep only those sentences of a document that contain words future or/and 
children
```

First, let's see which documents contain these key words

```
## extract all matches of future or children
str_extract_all(corpus, pattern = "future|children")
```

So far, I only found out how to exclude the sentences that contain my key words, which is the opposite of what I want to do.

```
## excluded sentences that contains future or children or both (?)
corpustrim <- corpus_trimsentences(corpus, exclude_pattern = 
"future|children")
summary(corpustrim)
```

The above command excludes sentences containing my key words.
My idea here with the corpus_trimsentences function is to exclude all sentences BUT those containing "future" and/or "children".

I tried with regular expression. However, I did not manage to do it. It does not return what I want.

I looked into the `corpus_reshape` and `corpus_subset` functions of the quanteda package but I can't figure out how to use them for my purpose.

Comment: could you reverse corpus_trimsentences to have all patterns except future and children?

Comment: Dear Adam, thank you for your answer:) Yes that was also my idea when I found the corpus_trimsentences function. I assume that that should work as well, it would be logical. However, I did not manage to do it (with my very very limited regex knowledge). Ken's solution is more straight forward :) But corpus_trimsentences function is one to keep in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it's `corpus_reshape()` and `corpus_subset()` that you want here.  Here's how to use them.

First, reshape the corpus to sentences.

```
library("quanteda")

data_corpus_inauguralsents <- 
  corpus_reshape(data_corpus_inaugural, to = "sentences")
data_corpus_inauguralsents
```

The use **stringr** to create a logical (Boolean) that indicates the presence or absence of the pattern, equal in length to the new sentence corpus.

```
containstarget <- 
  stringr::str_detect(texts(data_corpus_inauguralsents), "future|children")
summary(containstarget)
##    Mode   FALSE    TRUE 
## logical    4879     137
```

Then use `corpus_subset()` to keep only those with the pattern:

```
data_corpus_inauguralsentssub <- 
  corpus_subset(data_corpus_inauguralsents, containstarget)
tail(texts(data_corpus_inauguralsentssub), 2)
## 2017-Trump.30 
## "But for too many of our citizens, a different reality exists: mothers and children trapped in poverty in our inner cities; rusted-out factories scattered like tombstones across the landscape of our nation; an education system, flush with cash, but which leaves our young and beautiful students deprived of all knowledge; and the crime and the gangs and the drugs that have stolen too many lives and robbed our country of so much unrealized potential." 
## 2017-Trump.41 
## "And now we are looking only to the future."
```

Finally, if you want to put these selected sentences back into their original document containers, but without the sentences that did not contain the target words, then reshape again:

```
# reshape back to documents that contain only sentences with the target terms
corpus_reshape(data_corpus_inauguralsentssub, to = "documents")
## Corpus consisting of 49 documents and 3 docvars.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `tokens` function.

```
library(quanteda)

corpus <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural)

# tokens to keep
tok_to_keep <- tokens_select(tokens(corpus, what = "sentence"), pattern = "future|children", valuetype = "regex", selection = "keep")
```

This returns a list of all the speeches and sentences where the key words are present. Next you can unlist the list of tok_to_keep or do whatever you need to it to get what you want.